# Bad filename formed by collectstatic from jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.css?

Tags: django, collectstatic

I'm using Django 1.10 and am getting the following error message from collectstatic:

`ValueError: The file 'helpdesk/"images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png"' could not be found with [...ManifestStaticFilesStorage].`

I'm wondering if the problem is the apparently extraneous quotes in the filename. I would expect the filename to be:

`helpdesk/images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png` <-- No quotes

not:

`helpdesk/"images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png"` <-- Extraneous quotes

Should the filename *with* extraneous quotes be expected to work or am I correct in assuming that the root cause of this problem is a badly formed filename? If it's a badly formed filename, where should I go from here?

P.S. I've double checked and the PNG file is indeed located in the `helpdesk/images` folder. "helpdesk" is the name of the app that includes jquery-ui but I don't think this is a problem with the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Django's collectstatic chokes on url patterns that it finds in the comments of jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.css. Specifically, strings like

```
url(%22images%2Fui-icons_555555_256x240.png%22)
```

are matched and then processed into bogus file names like

```
helpdesk/"images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png"
```

The collectstatic error went away after I deleted the offending comments from jquery-ui-1.12.0.min.css.

Comment: For others who find their way here... I reported this and posted a small patch to fix it:  https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21080#comment:10